# A question on Rudin's Book " Principles of Mathematical Analysis"

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

On Theorem 2.27 (a), page 35, Rudin's proof is incomplete.
If it is not the case $E' \subset E$ then the proof is false.

Are you agree with this observation?

---

(The theorem is: “If $X$ is a metric space and $E\subset X$, then (a) $\bar E$ is closed,…”. The proof of (a) is: “If $p\in X$ and $p\notin\bar E$ then $p$ is neither a point of $E$ nor a limit point of $E$.  Hence $p$ has a neighborhood which does not intersect $E$.  The complement of $\bar E$ is therefore open.  Hence $\bar E$ is closed.”)

Comment: Perhaps you should state the problem for those of us that do not have a copy of the book handy.

Comment: What do you mean by $E'$?  Is that the set of limit points of $E$?

Comment: yes the set of all limit points of E

Answer (score 5):

Note that Rudin defines $\overline E = E \cup E'$. So, we always have $E' \subset \overline E$. So, the proof that $\overline E$ is closed is valid.

Comment: What about of the limits points of $E'$?

Comment: There is a theorem that the limit points of $E'$ are contained in $E'$ (I think this is given as an exercise).

Comment: Yes, I know this. But this is a second proof. I didn't say that the Theorem is false because of this.

Comment: Welcome to Rudin's minimalist style. The proof is correct, but very terse, and uses a previously proven theorem without referencing it explicitly.

Comment: Also, [related](http://abstrusegoose.com/12).

Answer (score 2):

The proof is complete.

By asserting $p \notin \overline{E}$, we implicitly state that $p \in \overline{E}^C$, where $(\cdot)^C$ denotes complement.

By definition, since $p \notin \overline{E}$, it is neither in $E$, nor is it in the set of limit points of $E$. Therefore, it has an open neighborhood completely contained in $\overline{E}^C$. Since this holds for *every* point $p \notin \overline{E}$, then $\overline{E}^C$ must be open. The complement of an open set is closed, so $\left(\overline{E}^C\right)^C = \overline{E}$ must be closed.

Comment: Your implication: "Therefore, it has an open neighborhood completely contained in $\bar{E}^C$" is not true. Because if x belongs to this neighborhood and $x \in E'$ (this can happen if $E' - E$ is a nonempty set) then $x \notin \bar{E}^C$

Comment: @youu It most certainly is true. $p$ is not a limit point of $E$. If $p$ were a limit point of $E$, then by the definition of a limit point, every punctured neighborhood of $p$ would intersect $E$. Since there must be at least one such neighborhood that does not, (by law of the excluded middle) this neighborhood, and all smaller neighborhoods, must be contained in $\overline{E}^C$ -- fulfilling the definition of openness.

Comment: Check my comment again

Comment: @youu Since your hesitation seems to be with regards to $E'$, suppose a neighborhood $N_r(p)$ of $p$ contained a point in $E'$. Since a neighborhood is open, then for any point $p'$ in that neighborhood, we can draw a smaller neighborhood $N_{r'}(p')$ around $p'$ completely contained within $N_r(p)$. But if $p'$ is a limit point of $E$, then *every* neighborhood around it, inlcuding $N_{r'}(p')$, must contain a point of $E$.

Comment: Therefore, either one of two things must be true: either we can draw a neighborhood about $p$ that doesn't include a limit point of $E$, or we cannot. If we can draw that neighborhood, then we're fine. If we cannot draw that neighborhood, then we contradict the assumption $p \in X, p \notin \overline{E}$.

Comment: You mean that the case that I described it cannot be happened?

Comment: Sure, it can happen, but if it happens you just pick a smaller neighborhood.

Comment: ok thanks! I check it again and I end up that it cannot happen the following: "the neighborhood contains a limit point of E". Because this goes to a contradiction.